# How to white-out part of an email in my browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, gmail, privacy

I'm trying to show someone part of an email to help her with some issues, but I want to protect some private information of my friend's that is in the email.  Does anyone have a method for whiting out a part of the email?

I want to share the email on-screen, in-browser.  I tried using CSS3, but Stylebot does not support CSS3, so I cannot target nth-child p's in the body.  So, I either need some CSS2 solution, or I need to find some software that allows me to pin up whiteout over text.

Comment: To remove blocks (rather than just words from a line), [The Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/) might be useful too. (On HTTPS sites, your browser might need to be told it's okay to load.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method I used:

Use "Stylebot", an add-on for Chrome, to make all of the text white.  This way, all of the text is invisible.  Then, you can highlight the text that you want someone to see.  It also can be very genuine because the sender's email address can be shown in connection with the email itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to send it as an e-mail; you should just set it like you are going to forward it and then erase the areas that contain sensitive information before sending.

If you wish to share it via screen shot. Take the screen shot and transfer it to a photo editor. Here you can then black or white out information as necessary.

If you wish to do it in person, you may print it out and use tape, white out or a marker. You can also keep it on the computer and set it like you are going to forward it but not give it a recipient; or, transfer it to something like MS Word, notepad, notes, whatever you typically use.

Comment: I'm not sure if I was specific enough.  I should look through the question.  But basically, I'm trying to do it on-screen.